# Remove ifs from Javascript code

Tags: functional-programming

Can i program without if statements in functional programming in JS?

In Haskell you can do pattern matching:
sign x |  x >  0        =   1
       |  x == 0        =   0
in js:

```
sing = x => {
  if (x > 0) return 1;
  else if (x == 0) return 0
}
```

I can do shorthand if operator something like this:

```
sign = x => x > 0 ? 1 (x == 0 ? 0 : x)
```

Can I make the code shorter without library and ?: operator above ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `if` statements as long as you provide an `else` branch, as the conditional operator does.

Comment: JavaScript does not have pattern matching

Comment: Also note that you have an implicit return if x is negative.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the answer your looking for but the shortest way to write this code is:

```
return !!x+0;
```

### explanation

- !!x casts x to a boolean: x>0 == true x = 0 == false;
- +0 casts to integer: true = 1, false = 0.

But no there is no other style than using ?: operator.

### javascript shorthand usefullness

In javascript you have other helpful tricks like:

- Automatically casting things to thruties or falsies. (when boolean required)
- Or operator returning the value, easy for null coalescing: `var name = null || 'joel' // name = 'joel'`

Comment: Thanks, but this is just for demonstration purposos ignore the specific function.

Comment: @user2693928 nope you only have these shorthand operators ?: